# Overlay in jQuery UI toolkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-plugins

Is there any overlay in the JQuery UI toolkit that offers a context arrow to the link/content that it relates to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By overlay I *think* you mean tooltip in this case.  The jQuery UI widgets doesn't have this built in, but there are some other options, [for example qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

[You can find the demos here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/).  If I'm right, I think the one you're most interested in would be [the corner options demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/corner).